# preg_replace for a template which excludes the specified set of words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to transform text file changing variable types by prepending them with specified namespace. But I need to skip base types such as `array` or `string`.

So the text

```
/**
 * @param ParamType $param
 * @return ReturnType
 */
public function SomeFunction(ParamType $param) {
   ...
}

/**
 * @param array $param
 * @return string
 */
public function OtherFunction($param) {
   ...
}
```

Should be converted to

```
/**
 * @param \My\Namespace\ParamType $param
 * @return \My\Namespace\ReturnType
 */
public function SomeFunction(\My\Namespace\ParamType $param) {
   ...
}

/**
 * @param array $param
 * @return string
 */
public function OtherFunction($param) {
   ...
}
```

My transformation now looks as follows

```
$classFileText = preg_replace(
    [
        '/@param\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+\$(\w+)/',
        '/@return\s+([A-Za-z]+)/',
        '/@var\s+([A-Za-z]+)/',
        '/\s+function\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s*\(\s*([A-Za-z]+)\s+\$(\w+)/',
    ],
    [
        '@param \\' . $typesNamespace . '\\\\$1 $\\2 ',
        '@return \\' . $typesNamespace . '\\\\$1',
        '@var \\' . $typesNamespace . '\\\\$1',
        ' function $1(\\' . $typesNamespace . '\\\\$2 $\\3',
    ],
    $classFileText
);
```

This works, but base types are prepended as others.

I've tried to solve this using this tip: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

And many others... But I failed.

p.s. I came across this, making the transformation of the WSDL schema into a set of classes to access the SOAP service

Comment: So, where's the problem with `/@param\s+(?!(?:array|string|callable)\s)([A-Za-z]+)\s+\$(\w+)/` (complete as needed) … As shown by the other question?

Comment: @bwoebi i don't know, but this not works... tried to use this pattern, it works fine in refiddle: http://refiddle.com/refiddles/579e914475622d2391020000 but in my code it is not working, "array" and "string" still matched

Comment: @bwoebi fixed, now works. looks like there was some typo in my code... many thanks! ))

Comment: @bwoebi Oh, those regular expressions... it's just some sort of black magic. Still don't understand how it works ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@bwoebi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153758/bwoebi) for the answer in comments!

Now works fine:

```
$classFileText = preg_replace(
    [
        '/@param\s+(?!(?:array|string)\s)([A-Za-z]+)\s+\$(\w+)/',
        '/@return\s+(?!(?:array|string)\s)([A-Za-z]+)/',
        '/@var\s+(?!(?:array|string)\s)([A-Za-z]+)/',
        '/\s+function\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s*\(\s*(?!(?:array|string)\s)([A-Za-z]+)\s+\$(\w+)/',
    ],
    [
        '@param \\' . $typesNamespace . '\\\\$1 \$$2 ',
        '@return \\' . $typesNamespace . '\\\\$1',
        '@var \\' . $typesNamespace . '\\\\$1',
        ' function $1(\\' . $typesNamespace . '\\\\$2 \$$3',
    ],
    $classFileText
);
```

I would be grateful if someone explain how it works ))